# Prove/Disprove: $T(u)=u $ s.t $T\neq I$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let the be $U\subseteq V$ a subset of a vector space $V$ s.t $Dim(U)<Dim(V)$
>
> Prove\Disprove: There is a linear transformation s.t $\forall u\in U ;T(u)=u $ when $T\neq I$

So it is easy to see that it is correct as if $V$ is the 3D space and $U=(x,y,0)$ both $I$ and the matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ sends each $u\in$ U to $u$ but I am trying to formalize the proof where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $V = U \oplus W$. Then $ \dim W \ge 1$. Define $T$ as follows: if $v \in V$ , then there are unique $u \in U$ amd $w \in W$ such that $v=u+w$. Then $T(v):=u$.

$T$ has the desired properties.